# Joining on Polymorphic relation, only one result returns

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

I'm trying to get achieve popular posts by locale. Below query somehow works but it's only gets one results.. In database there are four more test records exist.. Also it counts views wrong

```
$popularPostsByLocale = Post::select("post.id", "post.title", "post.slug",\DB::raw("SUM(views.views) as view_count"))
  ->join("views", function ($query) {
      $query->on("views.viewable_id", "post.id")
            ->where([
                 ["views.viewable_type", "App\Models\Post"],
                 ["views.locale", \LaravelLocalization::setLocale()]
            ]);
    })
    ->with("featured")
    ->where("post.status", "publish")
    ->orderBy("view_count","desc")
    ->take(5)
    ->get();
```

Where do I mistake and how can I fix it ?

Comment: I realized while asking.. I forgot to group them

Comment: You will need group by, however, there are non aggregated columns in your select so it might throw error if you have only_full_group_by enabled.